# adding integer to dictionary (TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable)

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, integer

I am trying to add a number inputted by the user next to the chosen value in the dictionary. I need to do it like this so many users can add to the same dictionary adding to the count but I get this error message

```py
inventory={'p': 0, 'd': 0, 'r': 0}

let = str(input("""From this selection:
1. p
2. d
3. r
Which letter would you like to produce?: """))
bottle_num = int(input("How Many numbers Would You Like?"))
for let in inventory:
    inventory[let] + bottle_num
print(inventory[let][0])
```

**produces output of**

```
From this selection:
1. p
2. d
3. r
Which letter would you like to produce?: r
How Many numbers Would You Like?5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/$$$$$$$$$$/add_to_dict.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(inventory[let][0])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

$ signs were added in

Comment: `inventory[let]` should return an integer. Hence the error with the addition subscript `[0]` which is like, e.g., `5[0]`.

Comment: Also, ```str(input(...))``` is redundant because the ```input``` function already returns a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot index integer

```py
inventory={'p': 0, 'd': 0, 'r': 0}
let = 'p' # for example 
inventory[let] # == 0

# we cannot index 0[0]
```

If you try execute:

```py
5[0] # you will get TypeError
# >>> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

What I imagine you want to do:

```py
inventory={'p': 0, 'd': 0, 'r': 0}

let = input("""From this selection:
1. p
2. d
3. r
Which letter would you like to produce?: """)


bottle_num = int(input("How Many numbers Would You Like? "))


inventory.update({let:inventory[let] + bottle_num})

print(inventory[let])
```

So we ask for which key in the dictionary we want to update. The keys are your elements, then we update the `{key: dictionary[key] + value}` the `dictionary[key]` gives us the current value which we add to it the bottle_num

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the way you are accessing the dictionary. Notice the following:

```py
inventory = {"p": 0, "d": 0, "r": 0}
let = "p"
print(inventory[let]) # ouputs => 0
```

This is leading to you doing:

```py
print(0[0])
```

Which is throwing you the error. Another thing to notice is the

```py
for let in inventory:
    inventory[let] + bottle_num
```

loop you have going. Notice that the following loop:

```py
inventory = {"p": 0, "d": 0, "r": 0}
let = "p"
for let in inventory:
    print(let)
```

outputs:

```
p
d
r
```

That is, you are printing the *keys* of your dictionary (remember: `dict = {key: value}`). What you are likely looking for is:

```py
inventory = {"p": 0, "d": 0, "r": 0}

let = str(
    input(
        """From this selection:
1. p
2. d
3. r
Which letter would you like to produce?: """
    )
)
bottle_num = int(input("How Many numbers Would You Like?"))
inventory[let] += bottle_num

print(inventory)
```

outputs:

```
From this selection:
1. p
2. d
3. r
Which letter would you like to produce?: p
How Many numbers Would You Like? 5
{'p': 5, 'd': 0, 'r': 0}
```